# Spring Security returns 401 for unsecured URL

Tags: spring, spring-security

Using Spring Security 4.0.3 from a Spring Boot 1.3.3 application.

The application has two types of HTTP contents : **"API"** a REST API and **"UI"** a web based used interface (Thymeleaf + Spring Web MVC).

Most endpoints of the REST API of the application are secured, using Basic, but some are not and should **always** be available.

The simplified configuration looks like:

```
        // In one method, the security config for the "API"
        httpSecurity
                .antMatcher("/api/**")
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/ping").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/**").hasRole("USER")
                .and()
                .httpBasic();

        // In another method, the security config for the "UI"
        httpSecurity
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/ui/", "/ui/index.html", "/ui/css/*", "/ui/js/*", "/ui/img/*").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/ui/user/**").hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers("/ui/**").denyAll()
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/ui/login.html").permitAll().failureUrl("/ui/login.html").defaultSuccessUrl("/ui/user/main.html")
                .and()
                .logout().logoutUrl("/ui/logout").permitAll().logoutSuccessUrl("/ui/login.html")
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
```

Accesses to secured endpoints work as expected.

But accesses to public endpoints such as ".../api/ping" **fail with a 401 when the user provided an invalid Basic authentication**. Of course such endpoints works fine when no or valid Basic authentication is provided.

This 401 from Spring Security is surprising. How can we implement a Spring Security configuration that never returns any 401 or 403 for selected endpoints?

Thank you for your time.

**Update 1** : added info about the "UI" existence and security config

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Order is important. Most specific rule (path) first:

```java
httpSecurity
    .antMatchers("/api/ping").permitAll()
    // and then the rest
```

This because if there is a match like on `antMatcher("/api/**")`, Spring Security will not evaluate later rules.

Comment: First, I Updated the question : added details about "UI". Then your proposal unfortunately does not work here since the initial "andMatcher('/api/**') seems required to ensure the two parts of the Spring Security config are separated.